# Is there any permission to delete vote records related to knowledge article?

Tags: apex, configuration, customization

I am able to delete vote records using system administrator but when I am trying with other user INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_OR_READONLY exception is thrown.

These vote records are related to knowledge article. I have gone through [this](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000249267&language=en_US&type=1) but it seem to unrelated for knowledge article's votes.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by moving delete records method to without sharing class and calling the method in with sharing class.

As the delete method execute in system mode there wont be any error message.